# html <audio> tag won't work in macOS Safari

Tags: html, safari, html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-player

Using Python and Flask, I have a GET method that returns wav data.

Using this API, I'm trying to fetch the audio and stream it on a simple webpage:

```
<audio preload="none" src="http://localhost:5000/audio/api/v1.0/fetch/audio_1" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9NsW.jpg)

But I cannot get it to work in [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF6vh.jpg)

The GET method is obviously working properly since it's working in Chrome and Firefox. If I save the audio via curl, sox shows me:

```
Input File     : 'tmp.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:10.42 = 166720 samples ~ 781.5 CDDA sectors
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Try making it instead of `audio/wav` to `audio/mpeg`

Comment: @Hipady no luck

Comment: Safari probably doesn't support WAV... which is really unfortunate.

Comment: @Brad Safari supports WAV since Version 4. https://caniuse.com/#search=wav